# c++ template class clarification

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

How come I could use the template class 'listmap' in this fashion.

In which, I could typedef listmap in .

```
typedef listmap<string,string> str_str_map;
```

The template of listmap is the following.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, class Less=xless<Key>>
class listmap
```

I could see the strings are the correspondence to typename key, and typename value, but why is class Less not needed in the typedef?

Comment: `class Less=xless<Key>` - default type, perhaps?

Comment: @sashoalm A stupid question doesn't automatically invalidate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default value for `Less` provided and it is the type `xless<Key>`. So if you do not provide the third parameter you will be using `xless<string>`(in your case).